# mutt with gmail imap: send email in background

Tags: gmail, imap, smtp, mutt, gmail-imap

I'm using mutt with gmail and everything works fine, but it is painfully slow at times. Much of this doesn't seem like it can be avoided, but I wondered if there wasn't a way to queue mail for send (using smtp.gmail.com) rather than having to wait for it to send in order to go back to the message list. Anyone know? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for me was to switch to [offlineimap](http://docs.offlineimap.org/en/latest/) + [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) + this in .muttrc: `set sendmail_wait=-1`.

For anyone with imap performance frustrations with mutt (using gmail or otherwise), offlineimap and these other settings are definitely the way to go.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you don't wait for the email to finish sending, there's a chance it will fail and you will probably not notice. For me, at least, I don't send enough emails that the speed win is worth the small chance that I could have an unnoticed failure to send.